# How to change Magento Custom Options title for all products

Tags: product, custom-options

I am using the same Custom Product Options for all of my products. For Example:

Option attribute: GIFT Wrap? With the dropdown options "Green Gift Wrap" and "Red Gift Wrap". Our "Red Gift Wrap" is replaced for "Blue Gift Wrap". Now I want to change the title "Red Gift Wrap" to "Blue Gift Wrap" for all products.

I tried to change the "title" in the "catalog_product_option_type_title" table with a query directly in the database. Now in our backend the "Red Gift Wrap" is replaced for the "Blue Gift Wrap". Unfortunately the products still shows "Red" instead of "Blue" at the frontend. I cleared all the caches, reindexed all indexes, optimized the database table without any result.

Comment: Any chance you're using full page cache? Changing those database values should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have full page cache installed and clear that if you do.